# Angular8 passing @input class object in child component then access this value in parent component not work

Tags: angular6, angular8

```
Below are child component code :

 @Input('enableAutoshutdown') enableAutoshutdown: EnableAutoshutdownObject;
    @Output() data = new EventEmitter<EnableAutoshutdownObject>();
    
    sendData() {
      let enableAutoshutdownObject = new EnableAutoshutdownObject();
      enableAutoshutdownObject.ShutdownTime = this.fgEnbleAutoShutdownVm.value.ShutdownTime;
      this.enableAutoshutdown = enableAutoshutdownObject;
      this.data.emit(this.enableAutoshutdown);
    }
    below are parent component code:
    <app-azure-support-enable-auto-shutdown [isEnableAutoshutdown]="isEnableAutoshutdown" [(enableAutoshutdown)]="enableAutoshutdown" ></app-azure-support-enable-auto-shutdown>
    
    .ts
    ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.enableAutoshutdown)
    }
```

But getting undefined.i want to pass value from child component to parent with object and using two way data binding I am following some document but not working

Answer (score 0):

<app-azure-support-enable-auto-shutdown [isEnableAutoshutdown]="isEnableAutoshutdown" (enableAutoshutdown)="enableAutoshutdown($event)" >

Comment: Thank you for the reply Yes this already working for  me but i don't want event handler . I want two way data binding thing please use below url :  https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding